# MongoDB - Update or Insert object in array in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following collection

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57315ba4846dd82425ca2408"),
"myarray" : [ 
         {
            userId : ObjectId("570ca5e48dbe673802c2d035"),
            point : 5
         },
         {
            userId : ObjectId("613ca5e48dbe673802c2d521"),
            point : 2
        },        
 ]}
```

and I want to add a new element to this array in C#, Could please to help me I try to do it's by $push but always give me this error. thanks

```
MongoDB.Driver.AddToSetUpdateDefinition<TDocument, TItem>.Render(IBsonSerializer<TDocument> documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)`enter code here`
```

Comment: what is this? this is not a JSON, this is even not a C# array initializer due to []?

Comment: this collection in MongoDB and I need to add a new element to myarry

Comment: `but always give me this error.` what error? i do not see any

Comment: @ihssan What is the issue?